# LaTeX Error: Command \c@T already defined

Tags: macros, counters

this is an easy question, but I couldn't find the answer just from other similar questions.

A lot of people often get an error in the form:

```
    LaTeX Error: Command \XYZ already defined. 
                 Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

usually, the problem is that they are using something that is defined in 2 different packages, so LaTeX is confused about what to do with the command.

My symptoms are similar:
 after lines

```
88     \begin{definition}
89     The distribution of a random variable $X$ is usually described by giving its {\bf distribution function}, $f(x) = P(X \leq x)$.
90     \end{definition}
```

my TeXShop is saying:

```
   89:LaTeX Error: Command \c@T already defined.
                   Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

So, I tried to find where could command \c@T be defined. I'm only using

```
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
    \usepackage{changepage}
```

and I don't really see how they could both define command c@T.

I looked at the list of all commands in LaTeX, at http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/doc-c.html#cmd-citetype, and I haven't even found such command, but it looked like some kind of counting is the problem. So, I admit that I also have

```
    \begin{document}
    \newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]
    \newcounter{definition}
```

which might be the place where I defined something in the wrong way, but I don't see why wouldn't this problem come up in the previous definitions.

If anyone had patience to solve this old problem again and explain it to me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are all those `<br\>`s *really* in your document and the log?

Comment: Ah, no, sorry about that, I added them by mistake when I was writing this post. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Your `\newenvironment` is not complete and this can lead to disaster. Add `{}{}` after `[Definition]`.

Comment: `\c@(thing)` is an internal part of the counter called `(thing)`, namely the part that stores the value. In your case, that would mean you ahve two `\newcounter{T}` in your code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What's apparently happening is the following: as @Ulrike remarks, your `\newenvironment` lacks its two mandatory arguments. It will instead pick up `\newcounter` and `definition`, since that is what follows.

What this does is that when you call `\begin{definition}`, you inadvertently call `\newcounter`, so

```
\begin{definition} The thing
```

turns into, with some technicalities omitted,

```
\newcounter The thing
```

i.e.

```
\newcounter{T}he thing
```

and that's where your counters come from and that's why you get an error: you probably have to definitions that start with "T"!

(To backtrack and solve your problem: I think you really mean to look at the amsthm package and its `\newtheorem` command?)

Comment: Wow!  I salute your detective work.

Comment: @Andrew: make enough mistakes, eventually you'll have seen most of them before. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, Ulrike and Ulrich! It was enough, as Ulrike suggested, to add {}{} after \newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{}{}
Thanks to Ulrich's explanation, I see how did the \c@T appear. Also, looking at the amsthm package will be useful for the future.    Vielen Dank!